# need help getting eclipse to work keep getting exit code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse, fixed, javaw

I've been hitting with this same problem for a while now. I thought I found the problem when my JDK was a 32 bit while my eclipse was a 64 but it doesn't seem to be the only problem. I tried to download a lower version (I had the jdk v8u45, I uninstalled it and tried with 7u17) and still nothing. I also tried to lower the value of the Xmx in the eclipse.ini file also nothing.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

And this is my ini file :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

UPDATE :
I've added the -vm line with the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe" to the eclipse.ini file and it is still not working !

UPDATE 2 : 
I got the latest JRE ( 8u45 ), JDK ( 7u79 since the 8u45 doesn't want to install on my computer ), eclipse Luna that are available for 64 bits and it still won't work ...

UPDATE 3 :
This problem is fixed, i don't get that error anymore, now i just can't load some dll, i'll see what i can do for now, thanks for the help

btw it seems that i simply had to remove the /javaw.exe from the -vm line in the the eclipse.ini ! ^^'

Comment: If you use a 32 bit OS, make sure all the tools are for 32 bit as well. If you use 64 bits, then use 64 bit tools. This includes **eclipse**.

Comment: Yeah as i've said, i had this problem before but i made sure that both the JDK / eclipse are both for 64 bits, and my computer is a 64 bits !

Answer (score 1):

Open the  eclipse.ini file and add, (make sure it is before -vmargs):

-VM
[path to x64 verstion of jdk] 
For example:

```
-VM
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Depends on your Java version, make changes to jre7. Also the reason is because you installed x64 version Eclipse, so you need to download x64 version JDK.

Comment: Still nothing, i put this path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin

Comment: ok, is your eclipse 64 or 32 bit?`Program Files (x86)` is 32 bit

Comment: The 'x86_64' in the launcher.library line shows this a 64 bit Eclipse, so a 64 bit Java is required.

Comment: @greg-449 my eclipse is a 64 bit and i've just installed the latest java for 64 bits, and it still won't work
Is the eclipse.ini supposed to be update automatically or do i have to do it manually ?

Comment: @HashMap my eclipse is a 64 bit and my computer is a 64bit, i just checked just in case i had it wrong all this time ! I dunno why my program files is marked as x86 but that's the only program files folder i have.

Comment: The eclipse.ini file is not updated by a Java install. The '-vm' and the path should be on separate lines and must come before any '-vmargs' line.